# bdb.BdbQuit raises when using pdb in Flask app running on uwsgi server

Tags: python-3.x, flask, uwsgi, gevent

I'm using [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/) library in my project. Because websockets need to "run in parallel" with main Flask app I'm required to use [gevent-websocket](https://pypi.org/project/gevent-websocket/) library. The problem occurs when I'm trying to set breakpoint for debugger in `create_app` method:

My `app.py` file:

```py
# monkey patching standard library before importing 
# other modules
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import os
import logging.config

from flask import Flask
from dynaconf import FlaskDynaconf
...
# other imports


def configure_app(app):
    '''
    Configure app settings.
    '''
    FlaskDynaconf(app)
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    logging.config.fileConfig(app.config.LOGGING_SETTINGS)

...

def create_app(run_from_celery=False):
    ''' 
    Create new Flask app instance.
    '''
    app = Flask('automoticz')
    configure_app(app)
    # ...
    return app
```

When I start server (I'm using [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ), I recieve following error:

```sh
$ uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:5000 \
      --gevent 1000 \
      --http-websockets \
      --master \
      --wsgi-file automoticz/wsgi.py \
      --callable app
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "automoticz/wsgi.py", line 3, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "./automoticz/app.py", line 138, in create_app
    configure_app(app)
  File "./automoticz/app.py", line 28, in configure_app
    logging.config.fileConfig(app.config.LOGGING_SETTINGS)
  File "./automoticz/app.py", line 28, in configure_app
    logging.config.fileConfig(app.config.LOGGING_SETTINGS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/bdb.py", line 48, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/bdb.py", line 67, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 22694)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 22702, cores: 1000)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 22703)
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x494fa0] ***
```

I've tried using patched pdb from [gevent-tools](https://pypi.org/project/gevent-tools/) but result was the same for `import gtools.pdb; gtools.pdb.set_trace()`

```py
 104         @app.before_request                                                                                          
 105         def log_request_info():                                                                                      
 106             import gtools.pdb                                                                                        
 107             gtools.pdb.set_trace()                                                                                   
 108  ->         log_request(request)                                                                                     
(Pdb++) 
2019-07-14 19:52:30 - flask.app - ERROR - Exception on /api/system/ws_devices [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./automoticz/app.py", line 108, in log_request_info
    log_request(request)
  File "./automoticz/app.py", line 108, in log_request_info
    log_request(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/bdb.py", line 48, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/bdb.py", line 67, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
```

Is there any way to make `pdb` work correctly when running under `gevent`?

Comment: I hope you are using a `WSGIServer` from `gevent`? `from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987456/python-gevent-pywsgi-server-with-ssl

Comment: Can I use `gevent.pywsgi.WSGIServer` with `uwsgi`?

Comment: Yes, `wsgi` is a standard and any `wsgi` compatible server works with `uwsgi`

Comment: @TarunLalwani okay I got pdb to work with gevent with WSGIServer as you said but it only works if run it with `serve_forever()`. When passing callable cretated ad `server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 5000), app)` the Flask app is not loaded in uwsgi and i recieve `*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***` message

Comment: Please provide a minimal git repo to debug

Comment: @TarunLalwani [repo](https://github.com/xbound/automoticz-server). `wsgi.py` is my main file where i create callable which i then pass to uwsgi server: `uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:5000 \
      --gevent 1000 \
      --http-websockets \
      --master \
      --wsgi-file automoticz/wsgi.py \
      --callable server`

Comment: how do i get the DB tables to get created in your project?

Comment: `pipenv run flask db upgrade`

Comment: Still getting some error, `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: oauth2_credentials`

Comment: try `pipenv run flask migrate` and then `pipenv run flask upgrade`

Comment: also comment code that inside `with app.app_context()` it requires to work with Google platform but you will need to generate oauth2 keys and other staff

Comment: Let's chat on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196749/discussion-for-bdb-bdbquit-raises-when-using-pdb-in-flask-app-running-on-uwsgi-se

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging a bit I realised you shouldn't use

```py
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
application = WSGIServer((application.config.SERVER_HOST, application.config.SERVER_PORT), application)
```

As it doesn't work. So you can use your older `wsgi.py` version. Now the issue arises because when you are `uwsgi` there is no `stdin` and it is pointed to `/dev/null`. Since there is no stdin, the debugger cannot launch. See below thread

[How to debug python application under uWSGI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427948/how-to-debug-python-application-under-uwsgi)

So what you want is to add the `--hounor-stdin` and `--gevent` while running `uwsgi`

```sh
uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:5000 \
 --gevent 10 \
 --http-websockets \
 --master \
 --wsgi-file automoticz/wsgi.py \
 --honour-stdin
```

And now the debugging works

[image: Debugging working]